# How to show caller image on iOS native ui call by using callkit framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, voip, callkit

In my iOS app, I am using CallKit and PushKit for VOIP Call. By using CallKit, I am able to show native call ui and everything fine but I need show native call UI with caller image. How to do this?

[Image1 without caller image at receiver side "my app currently behave like this"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY6P1.jpeg)

[image: jpg]

[Image2 with caller image at receiver side "I want like this in my app"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JEoy.png)

[image: jpg]

Answer (score 6):

A photo will be shown on the native incoming call UI if the user's Contacts database contains a Contact record matching the `CXHandle` specified for the incoming call via a `CXCallUpdate`, assuming that Contact record contains a photo.

To test this, you should be able to create a Contact card with a photo and a specific handle (e.g. a phone number or email address), then trigger an incoming call from that handle and ensure your app reports a `CXCallUpdate` with the `remoteHandle` property set to the `CXHandle` matching the one on the Contact card.

Answer (score 0):

After trying couple of other things final got the conclusion that you must a hig res image if you want to cover background image of caller.

Initially I was using 500*600 image which was showing as thumbnail then I tried with an image 1242*1863 and it's simply work.

Let me know in case anyone need help in this. Thanks